# How o use Hibernate Tools with existing Spring project and annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I just installed Hibernate Tools from JBoss in my Eclipse and was hoping to work with mapping diagram and Hsql editor, but something isn't setup right. I use annotations in all of my classes and don't use hibernate.properties and hibernate.cfg. 
My setup is: Maven, Hibernate, Spring MVC and I already annotated my classes with relationships. 
How to bind my annotated classes with Hibernate Tools?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by binding annotated classes with hibernate?

Comment: @fg78nc I meant with Hibernate Tools so I can use a mapping diagramm and hsql editor.

Comment: Please see if this will help [link](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/)

Comment: your question is unclear. are you getting any exception when you run the project?

Comment: @RajithPemabandu Nope, my projects works fine just want to use Hibernate Tools with it.

Comment: @fg78nc I think this might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: fine, good luck.